# Nginx routing Django Web App links to wrong path

Tags: django, nginx, centos, django-deployment

I have a django app where the hompage routes correctly, but when I try to click on any of the links I get a 404 error.  I looked at the logs and see:

```
*1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/pricing" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

which tells me that nginx is not looking at my project folder but instead what seems to be a default setting.  I am using centos, so I had to manually setup sites-available and sites-enabled, which I have used to get the homepage working.  As such there is no default conf to disable.  I am unsure how to get nginx to route to my path instead of the default.  My nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
user so_dev;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; #added by me
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed a bad tutorial which had a typo in it.  If you happen to follow same type, inside your nginx sites-available file you should put:

```
location /
```

and NOT

```
location = /
```

https://www.shellvoide.com/hacks/installing-django-application-with-nginx-mysql-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-vps/

Comment: Me too! Same tutorial, same issue. Thanks for posting the answer here. I'll contact the dev on the website and tell him this is an issue.